# Why does vlookup not work with dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have to find a value by date in Google Sheets between multiple tabs. I boiled it down and boiled it down until I made the most simple example I could find, and yet it still didn't work. Date notations are the same, the dates are a match, but still it reads like a number and returns an n/a. Made an example sheet, feel free to mess around

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZIhuacnFqHQwO_m5RTnXdks2Psu4qei6Vp6HWuPipfs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or this

```
=index(C:C;MATCH(A6;D:D;0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1; {D:D\ C:C}; 2; 0))
```